# Correctly duplicating a JS object when building multiple GET requests (with Axios)

Tags: javascript, object, get, axios

Below is a snippet that searches HackerNews api for the keyword 'java' by making multiple requests to retrieve the first N pages of data

Ideally it should retrieve the first 3 pages of the data set:

```
https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=java&page=0
https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=java&page=1
https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=java&page=2
```

Here is code, which is [also available as a CodePen](https://codepen.io/ajiyer/pen/dyGewmb)

```
// Fetch all HackerNews posts with the search string 'java'
const url = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date';

const config = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
  params: { query: 'java', page: null }
};

const numPagesToFetch = 3;

// Build a series of requests, one for each page
let requests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numPagesToFetch; i++) {
  
  // Duplicate the `config` object for each request
  let requestCfg = Object.assign({}, config);

  // The only `param` changing for each request is `?page=`
  // HN API starts numbering from page 0
  requestCfg.params.page = i;

  console.log(`Generating request for page ${requestCfg.params.page}`);
  requests.push(axios.get(url, requestCfg));
}

// Wait on all requests to complete in parallel, then handle the output
Promise.all(requests).
  then((responses) => {
    // Should be equal to numPagesToFetch (3)
    console.log(`Number of responses: ${responses.length}`);

    for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
      // Print out some info about each response
      const firstId = responses[i].data.hits[0].story_id;
      const requestUrl = responses[i].request.responseURL;
      console.log(`Dataset Response from ${requestUrl} starts with id ${firstId}`);
    }
  }).
  catch(error => {
    console.log('There was an error');
  })
```

When I run this, it seems to be retrieving the same page (the last page) multiple times

```
https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=java&page=2
https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=java&page=2
https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=java&page=2
```

I feel like it has something to do with how JS or axios handles references to variables. As I build each request and increment the `page`, it's impacting all the other requests constructed with that same variable. I even took care to "duplicate" the `config` object, but it doesn't help.

Any idea why it's making the same request 3 times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not cloning it deeply, you only clone the root object but the inner objects still point to their original object...you can either use https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep or use this little trick of converting it to a string then parsing as object:

```
let requestCfg = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This finally fixed the issue I've been trying to figure out for 2 days :)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you 